# Как сделать переадресацию, если сайт расположен где-то, кроме указанного домена?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Если сайт размещён на своём же домене name.ru то переадресация не нужна.

Если сайт стырили и разместили на левом сайте, то должно переадресовать на `name.ru`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `стырили сайт`, эм, что простите?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, как я понял, если украли контент или дизайн, нужно автоматически переадресовывать на оригинальный сайт.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев , Да

Comment: `document.location.href` же. Только вряд ли те, кому хватило ума "стырить" у вас сайт не смогут убрать любые ваши переадресации.

Comment: Правильно думаете. Но хочется побольше защит поставить

Comment: Все ваши защиты бессмысленны. Лучше вместо того, чтобы тратить время на _технические_ средства борьбы с злоумышленниками, переходите в _правовое_ поле.

Comment: В смысле?? По закону

Comment: Ага, по закону.

Answer (score 3):

## Оставьте эту затею

Кому действительно нужно скопировать ваш сайт или контент, тот его скопирует, и вряд ли его остановит какая-либо защита. Если ваш сайт копируют, значит вы действительно создали что-то хорошее

---

Если вы все же хотите как-то защититься от копирования **технически** с помощью javascript...

#### Самый простой способ

Если нужно точное совпадение по домену, то вот такой код:

```
if (window.location.host !== 'name.ru') {
  window.location = 'http://name.ru'
}
```

Если нужно разрешить размещать ваш код на поддоменах, то вот такой:

```
if (/\.name\.ru$|^(w{3}\.)?name\.ru$/.test(window.location.host)) {
  window.location = 'http://name.ru'
}
```

#### С обфускацией выполняемых действий

Вот так для строгого сравнения:

```
// Разворот строки
function rv(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

// Экранирование домена перед подстановкой в регулярное выражение
function e(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

// Редирект
function r(d) {
    var t = 'h' + (new Array(3).join('t')) + 'p:' + (new Array(3).join('/')) + d;
    window[rv('noitacol')][rv('ferh')] = t;
}

// Проверка текущего домена
function c(d) {
    var p = '/^' + e(d) + '$/';
    return (new RegExp(p)).test(window.location.host) ? true : r(d);
}

var k = 'name.ru';
c(k);
```

Вот так для разрешения размещения на поддоменах:

```
// Разворот строки
function rv(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

// Экранирование домена перед подстановкой в регулярное выражение
function e(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

// Редирект
function r(d) {
    var t = 'h' + (new Array(3).join('t')) + 'p:' + (new Array(3).join('/')) + d;
    window[rv('noitacol')][rv('ferh')] = t;
}

// Проверка текущего домена
function c(d) {
    var p = '/\.' + e(d) + '$|^(\u0077{3}\.)?' + e(d) + '$/';
    return (new RegExp(p)).test(window.location.host) ? true : r(d);
}

var k = 'name.ru';
c(k);
```

Сам домен не шифруется, но вы можете затруднить поиск по нему, разбив строку на несколько частей или изначально зашить закодированное неким алгоритмом значение, к которому сразу применяется расшифровка перед постановкой в функцию `c()`.

Использована информация отсюда:
[How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/959004/2486051)
[Javascript для PHP функции: str_repeat](http://javascript.ru/php/str_repeat#comment-2950)
[Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/2486051)